# Polymorphism with callables in Python

Tags: python, instance, callable

I have an interface class called iResource, and a number of subclasses, each of which implement the "request" method. The request functions use socket I/O to other machines, so it makes sense to run them asynchronously, so those other machines can work in parallel.

The problem is that when I start a thread with iResource.request and give it a subclass as the first argument, it'll call the superclass method. If I try to start it with "type(a).request" and "a" as the first argument, I get "" for the value of type(a). Any ideas what that means and how to get the true type of the method? Can I formally declare an abstract method in Python somehow?

EDIT: Including code.

```
def getSocialResults(self, query=''):
    #for a in self.types["social"]: print type(a)
    tasks = [type(a).request for a in self.types["social"]]
    argss = [(a, query, 0) for a in self.types["social"]]

    grabbers = executeChainResults(tasks, argss)

    return igrabber.cycleGrabber(grabbers)
```

"executeChainResults" takes a list "tasks" of callables and a list "argss" of args-tuples, and assumes each returns a list. It then executes each in a separate thread, and concatenates the lists of results. I can post that code if necessary, but I haven't had any problems with it so I'll leave it out for now.

The objects "a" are DEFINITELY not of type iResource, since it has a single constructor that just throws an exception. However, replacing "type(a).request" with "iResource.request" invokes the base class method. Furthermore, calling "self.types["social"][0].request" directly works fine, but the above code gives me: "type object 'instance' has no attribute 'request'".

Uncommenting the commented line prints `<type 'instance'>` several times.

Comment: Can you show some code? From the top of my head, I'd say that this shouldn't happen.

Comment: You need to read up on the concept of Duck Typing

Comment: Please, regardless of what you do, start inehriting your classes from `object` - it is the correct thing to do since Python 2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the bound method object itself:

```
tasks = [a.request for a in self.types["social"]]
#        ^^^^^^^^^
grabbers = executeChainResults(tasks, [(query, 0)] * len(tasks))
#                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you insist on calling your methods through the base class you could also do it like this:

```
from abc import ABCMeta
from functools import wraps

def virtualmethod(method):
    method.__isabstractmethod__ = True
    @wraps(method)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return getattr(self, method.__name__)(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

class IBase(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    @virtualmethod
    def my_method(self, x, y):
        pass

class AddImpl(IBase):
    def my_method(self, x, y):
        return x + y

class MulImpl(IBase):
    def my_method(self, x, y):
        return x * y

items = [AddImpl(), MulImpl()]

for each in items:
    print IBase.my_method(each, 3, 4)

b = IBase()  #  <-- crash
```

Result:

```
7
12
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testvirtual.py", line 30, in <module>
    b = IBase()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class IBase with abstract methods my_method
```

Python doesn't support interfaces as e.g. Java does. But with the `abc` module you can ensure that certain methods must be implemented in subclasses. Normally you would do this with the `abc.abstractmethod()` decorator, but you still could not call the subclasses method through the base class, like you intend. I had a similar question once and I had the idea of the `virtualmethod()` decorator. It's quite simple. It essentially does the same thing as `abc.abstratmethod()`, but also redirects the call to the subclasses method. The specifics of the `abc` module can be found in [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html) and in [PEP3119](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/).

BTW: I assume you're using Python >= 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

The reference to "`<type "instance" >`" you get when you are using an "old style class" in Python - i.e.: classes not derived from the "object" type hierarchy. Old style classes are not supposed to work with *several* of the newer features of the language, including descriptors and others. AND, among other things,  - you can't retrieve an attribute (or method) from the class of an old style class using what you are doing:

```
>>> class C(object):
...    def c(self): pass
... 
>>> type (c)
<class '__main__.C'>
>>> c = C()
>>> type(c).c
<unbound method C.c>
>>> class D: #not inheriting from object: old style class
...   def d(self): pass
... 
>>> d = D()
>>> type(d).d
>>> type(d)
<type 'instance'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'instance' has no attribute 'd'
>>>
```

Therefore, just make your base class inherit from "object" instead of "nothing"  and check if you still get the error message when requesting the "request" method from type(a) :

As for your other observation: 
"The problem is that when I start a thread with iResource.request and give it a subclass as the first argument, it'll call the superclass method."

It seems that the "right" thing for it to do is exactly that:

```
>>> class A(object):
...   def b(self):
...     print "super"
... 
>>> class B(A):
...   def b(self):
...     print "child"
... 
>>> b = B()
>>> A.b(b)
super
>>>
```

Here, I call a method in the class "A" giving it an specialized instance of "A" - the method is still the one in class "A".